# Weighted Average Canceling Units

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Lets say I own 91% of a company, and the company produces $50 in profit per year. What share of the companies profits do I own?

Here is how I set this up:

$\frac{91\:my\:share}{100\:total\:shares}\cdot 50\:dollars\:for\:the\:total\:share$

I'm struggling to figure out how to cross of the units. I should end up with the "my share" times dollars, which means "total shares" and "total share" should cross off.
Did I set this up incorrectly?

Comment: The term is $\frac{91\, \textrm{shares}}{100\, \textrm{shares}}\cdot \$50 \textrm{ per year}=0.91\cdot \$50 \textrm{ per year}=\$45.5 \textrm{ per year}$

Comment: I appreciate the response! I don't see how the units cancel though from your example.

Comment: It pleases me, that the comment has helped.